# optimizaton SQL query by using already calculated variables

Tags: mysql, sql

In project we use MySQL table for analytics. It is big table 40+ columns, more than 10kk rows.
A big part of time in query take result calculation (50+ cols in result). Idea is to reuse calculated values as variables and make it faster.
Query example:

```
SELECT col1, SUM(col2) as s_col2, SUM(col3) as s_col3, AVG(col2) as a_col2, ...,
SUM(col2)/SUM(col3) as aaa,
ROUND(AVG(col4), 2) as a_col4,
ROUND(SUM(col5), 2) as s_col5,
ROUND(SUM(col5)/AVG(col4), 2) as zzz,
...
JOIN ...
GROUP_BY ...
ORDER BY ...
```

Idea is to use @variable, for example:

```
SELECT col1, @s_col2 := SUM(col2) as s_col2, @s_col3 := SUM(col3) as s_col3, ...,
@s_col2/@s_col3 as aaa,
```

It works only for a few variables which are outside function, but I don't need additional columns for every variable.

```
@a_col4 := AVG(col4), #I don`t need this column
@s_col5 := SUM(col5), #I don`t need this column
ROUND(@a_col4, 2) as a_col4,
ROUND(@s_col5, 2) as s_col5,
ROUND(@s_col5/@a_col4, 2) as zzz,
```

**How I can assign variables inside functions?**

```
ROUND(@a_col4 := AVG(col4), 2) as a_col4,   #not works
ROUND((@s_col5 := SUM(col5)), 2) as s_col5, #not works
ROUND(@s_col5/@a_col4, 2) as zzz,
```

**UPDATED:**
Thanks guys for your help.

> The MySQL engine is probably smart enough to compute the value of
> SUM(col5) only once

I am not sure because for a big quantity of columns

```
SUM(col1) as a1,
SUM(col1) as a2,
SUM(col1) as a3,
SUM(col1) as a4,
SUM(col1) as a5,
```

Is slower than

```
@a1 := SUM(col1) as a1,
@a1 as a2,
@a1 as a3,
@a1 as a4,
@a1 as a5,
```

> you can also use CTE for reusing table results

I tried, but some values use too many functions one inside another, sometimes 7 levels deep and not all variables can be reused in this way (COALESCE(ROUND(COALESCE(ROUND(SUM(AVG(IF..AND...OR...AND)...

All my changes, (15 variables) have very small effect, for the small period it takes 139 sec (was 151 sec), but some of our reports take a few hours and we need stronger optimisation.

We will try to analyse server bottlenecks, maybe use partitioning, sharding...

> As a general rule, the number of rows touched is much more important
> to how long a query will take than the functions being evaluated.

The number of rows is always big, a lot of indexes and it works really fast. If I comment columns where we need calculations and only select existing it will take 40 sec (instead of 150)

Comment: I'd recommend trying a common table expression (CTE) in which you calculate your reusable values, and then select them as needed into your primary query.

Comment: The MySQL engine is probably smart enough to compute the value of `SUM(col5)` only once and reuse it in all expressions. That optimization is already working.

Comment: With `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`, you run the risk of getting the "wrong" values.  Aggregation (`SUM`, etc) is done _after_ `JOINing` and _before_ `GROUPing`.  Check the results, if Count and Sum are too big, then you may need to involve a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

The qwy to do it in sql is to use the Select withe with the sum and average as basis for an outer select

```
SELECT *,
    s_col2/s_col3 as aaa,
    ROUND(a_col4, 2) as a_col4,
    ROUND(acol5, 2) as s_col5,
    ROUND(s_col5/a_col4, 2) as zzz.
    ...
FROM
    (SELECT col1, SUM(col2) as s_col2, SUM(col3) as s_col3, AVG(col2) as a_col2, ...,

    ...
    JOIN ...
    GROUP_BY ...) t1
ORDER BY ...
```

in MySQL 8 you can also use CTE for reusing tbale rewsults see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)

Comment: Unless I'm really mistaken there's no need to do this. The engine is already doing it.

Comment: i doubt it, but a explain of the original and my solution would be interesting. as far as i understand it ysql would rtun all sums again and would not take it out of a temporary table of some kind

Comment: I'm with nbk, but I don't have proof.  I don't think a simple `EXPLAIN` will say; try using `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` and the Optimizer Trace.

Comment: A quick experiment with those diagnostics gave me no clue of whether the values were 'cached'.  (This was on 8.0; MariaDB might be different.)

Comment: Even if nbk is "right", it could be slower -- having a subquery (or CTE) could be more costly than repeated evaluation of the aggregates.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry.

As a general rule, the number of rows touched is much more important to how long a query will take than the functions being evaluated.

A similar question comes from the choice between these:

```
SELECT foo, COUNT(*) FROM x GROUP BY foo ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 5;
SELECT foo, COUNT(*) FROM x GROUP BY foo ORDER BY    1     DESC LIMIT 5;
```

I often do the latter because it is fewer keystrokes.  I have not been able to determine whether it is faster.

I suggest you write your question in the simplest or clearest way.  A subquery (or CTE) may actually be clearer in spite of taking more keystrokes.

Clarity and correctness are more important than speed.

And beware -- With both `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` in the query, you may have *incorrect* results.  The `JOIN` is done *before* the aggregation; the `GROUP BY` comes *after*.  Check to see if `COUNT` or `SUM` is bigger than it should be.  If so, you will *need* a subquery or CTE.